# how to use structured query in google sheets for fetching data in json format?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, query-string, google-sheets-api

I am fetching data in json format from google sheets. This sheet has user information . So one column in sheet is `id` Currently I am fetching all sheet data and filtering out on frontend. which takes time to load. So I read about google sheet's structured queries. I tried it but not working for me.

here is `http` request which I am using to fetch data

```
http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/spreadsheet_id/o7eb08/public/full?alt=json
```

How I used structured queries in `http` request which is not working

```
http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/ss_id/o7eb08/public/full?sq=id=75?alt=json
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

The query string you are using is malformed. The `?` symbol is used to specify a query string in your URL. This means that after that symbol the parser will find the parameters expressed as `key=value`.

In your example you are using `?` twice.

```
http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/ss_id/o7eb08/public/full?sq=id=75?alt=json
                                                                 *^*      *^*
                                                                USING "?" TWICE
```

The parser here will interpret the second `?` symbol as part of the `sq` value, resulting in an invalid parameter error.

The correct way to send multiple parameters in a URL is using the `&` symbol:

```
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/spreadsheet_id/grid_id/public/full?sq=id=75&alt=json
```

### Reference

[Query String](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string)